# Did neandertales have a soul? From when do people exists/have soul?

Tags: soul

Does the church agree with some kind of Darwin evolution and big bang theory? If so, from when does human exists? If we think of human as we have soul, did neandertales had one? Was it like this individual does not have soul yet but from now, his children do have a soul and are the first people that could go to heaven?

Comment: Not realy. Genisis 1:1 In the beginning God created the heavens and the earth. 2 Now the earth was formless and empty, darkness was over the surface of the deep, and the Spirit of God was hovering over the waters. Genesis 1:25 God made the wild animals according to their kinds, the livestock according to their kinds, and all the creatures that move along the ground according to their kinds. And God saw that it was good.

Comment: Welcome to Bible Hermeneutics SE and thank you for your contribution. Unfortunately, your question doesn't focus on a particular scripture as per the site's parameters. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803).

Comment: Genesis 2:7 Then the Lord God formed a man[c] from the dust of the ground and breathed into his nostrils the breath of life, and the man became a living being. That is where the man & soul came.  At least I believe that.

Comment: +1 as I believe you will have other questions and we welcome you to ask without fear. Most of us will share what we believe with honesty. God Bless.

Comment: thanks for your answer! yes, I knew that, but many things in Bible are written metaphorically, so people living in ancient times could understand, and as I think the details are not so important as the point of it, but it is written that man was formed from dust, it could mean, maybe, evolved from earth, microorganisms, animal? Personally I think the evolution happened. We do have even proofs of neandertales, bones etc., so, did they have a soul?

Comment: @Rikib1999 The text is clear "Lord God formed a man[c] from the dust of the ground" it is clear from here that there is a creator and there was a created being once the creative act was complete. Now you can always say all this happened through gradual evolution. Only 2 problems you have now. 1. How do you get G-d out of the picture? 2. Many scientists today agree that the complexity of creation cannot be explained by random mutations and events.

Answer (score 1):

Animals have souls.  The Hebrew word for soul is נֶפֶשׁ (nephesh), and it's translated creature in Gen. 1:20-21.

> And God said, “Let the waters swarm with swarms of living **creatures**, and let birds fly above the earth across the expanse of the heavens.” 21 So God created the great sea creatures and every living **creature** that moves, with which the waters swarm, according to their kinds, and every winged bird according to its kind. And God saw that it was good.
> (Gen. 1:20–21, ESV)

> וַיֹּ֣אמֶר אֱלֹהִ֔ים יִשְׁרְצ֣וּ הַמַּ֔יִם שֶׁ֖רֶץ נֶ֣פֶשׁ חַיָּ֑ה וְעֹוף֙ יְעֹופֵ֣ף עַל־הָאָ֔רֶץ עַל־פְּנֵ֖י רְקִ֥יעַ הַשָּׁמָֽיִםa‬׃
> וַיִּבְרָ֣א אֱלֹהִ֔ים אֶת־הַתַּנִּינִ֖ם הַגְּדֹלִ֑ים וְאֵ֣ת כָּל־נֶ֣פֶשׁ הַֽחַיָּ֣ה׀ הָֽרֹמֶ֡שֶׂת אֲשֶׁר֩ שָׁרְצ֨וּ הַמַּ֜יִם לְמִֽינֵהֶ֗םa‬ וְאֵ֨ת כָּל־עֹ֤וף כָּנָף֙ לְמִינֵ֔הוּ וַיַּ֥רְא אֱלֹהִ֖ים כִּי־טֹֽוב׃
> (Gen. 1:20–21, MT)

Other than that, there is no agreement either way.

Comment: No, animals do not have a soul. They will not go to heaven etc. They do not know what is good and bad. They have some kind of consciousness, but not soul.

Comment: I agree. Tanakh says that only for man G-d breathed into his nostrils. **Genesis 2:7** And the Lord God formed man of dust from the ground, and He breathed into his nostrils the soul of life, and man became a living soul. **Genesis 2:19** And the Lord God formed from the earth every beast of the field and every fowl of the heavens, and He brought [it] to man to see what he would call it, and whatever the man called each living thing, that was its name.

Comment: The soul is just the difference between a live body and dead body.  Only humans are created in God's image.  Try reading the scriptures in Hebrew and Greek.

Comment: In Genesis 2:7 soul translates the Hebrew word נֶפֶשׁ (nephesh).  Living thing in Gen. 2:19 also translates the Hebrew נֶפֶשׁ (nephesh).

Comment: You are right that Genesis 2:19 uses the word Nephesh for "and whatever **the man**"  called. Please see interlinear Hebrew. God bless.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J1sgk0uioP5RWA-exdJtIreVKeZSBRCR/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The man or Adam is הָֽאָדָ֛ם. Living thing or living creature translates  ‬נֶ֥פֶשׁ חַיָּ֖ה.

Comment: Living soul and living creature translate the same two Hebrew words ‬נֶ֥פֶשׁ חַיָּ֖ה.

Comment: then the LORD God formed the man of dust from the ground and breathed into his nostrils the breath of life, and the man became a living creature.
(Gen. 2:7, ESV)